# Why does the light beam moves diagonally?

Tags: time, relativity

In almost all articles that explains Relativity or Time dilation.
They start by saying the the Light is absolute and isn't affected by the inertial frames of reference yet when they start to explain time Dilation the light beam gains the velocity of the ship or any items that is postulated to explain so it moves diagonally ?
Doesn't it contradict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say:

> They start by saying the the Light is absolute and isn't affected by the inertial frames of reference

but this is not true. The **speed** of light is constant but its **direction** is not. The direction of a light beam can and will look different in different frames of reference, but in all those frames the speed of the light will be $c$.

Comment: So how come does it gain the change in direction ?

Comment: The light beam itself doesn't change direction. It just looks as if it's travelling in different directions when looked at from different points of view.